# Flutter Firestore read an array from firestore

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to use a StreamBuilder in conjunction with a ListView.builder to display data stored in an array on firebase.

I've tried using the code below to access the array but I really don't know what I'm doing wrong.

```
class Home extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return StreamBuilder<List<Beacon>>(
        stream: DatabaseService().beacons,
        builder: (context, snapshot) {
          return BeaconList(),
        }
    );
  }
}

class BeaconList extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _BeaconListState createState() => _BeaconListState();
}

class _BeaconListState extends State<BeaconList> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final beacons = Provider.of<List<Beacon>>(context) ?? [];

    return ListView.builder(
      itemCount: beacons.length,
      itemBuilder: (context, index) {
        return BeaconTile(beacon: beacons[index]);
      },
    );
  }
}

class BeaconTile extends StatefulWidget {
  final Beacon beacon;
  BeaconTile({this.beacon});
  @override
  _BeaconTileState createState() => _BeaconTileState();
}

class _BeaconTileState extends State<BeaconTile> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Padding(
      padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 8),
      child: Card(
        margin: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(20, 6, 20, 0),
        child: ListTile(
          leading: CircleAvatar(
            radius: 25,
            backgroundColor: widget.beacon.bid Colors.green[400],
          ),
          title: Text("Connection made"),
          subtitle: Text("ID: ${widget.beacon.bid}"),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class Beacon {
  String bid;
  Beacon({this.bid});
}

final DocumentReference beaconCollection = Firestore.instance.collection("LocationData").document("BeaconData");

List<Beacon> _beaconListFromSnapshot(DocumentSnapshot snapshot) {
  List<Beacon> beaconList = [];
  for (int i = 0; i < snapshot.data.length; i++) {
    print(i);
    beaconList.add(Beacon(bid: snapshot.data[i]));
  }
  return beaconList;
}

Stream<List<Beacon>> get beacons {
  return beaconCollection.get()
      .then((snapshot) {
    try {
      return _beaconListFromSnapshot(snapshot);
    } catch(e) {
      print(e.toString());
      return null;
    }
  }).asStream();
}
```

Running the above code I get the error:

````
I/flutter (30206): ══╡ EXCEPTION CAUGHT BY WIDGETS LIBRARY ╞═══════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
I/flutter (30206): The following ProviderNotFoundException was thrown building BeaconList(dirty, state:
I/flutter (30206): _BeaconListState#6361b):
I/flutter (30206): Error: Could not find the correct Provider<List<Beacon>> above this BeaconList Widget
I/flutter (30206): 
I/flutter (30206): This likely happens because you used a `BuildContext` that does not include the provider
I/flutter (30206): of your choice. There are a few common scenarios:
I/flutter (30206): 
I/flutter (30206): - The provider you are trying to read is in a different route.
I/flutter (30206): 
I/flutter (30206):   Providers are "scoped". So if you insert of provider inside a route, then
I/flutter (30206):   other routes will not be able to access that provider.
I/flutter (30206): 
I/flutter (30206): - You used a `BuildContext` that is an ancestor of the provider you are trying to read.
I/flutter (30206): 
I/flutter (30206):   Make sure that BeaconList is under your MultiProvider/Provider<List<Beacon>>.
I/flutter (30206):   This usually happen when you are creating a provider and trying to read it immediately.
I/flutter (30206): 
I/flutter (30206):   For example, instead of:
I/flutter (30206): 
I/flutter (30206):   ```
I/flutter (30206):   Widget build(BuildContext context) {
I/flutter (30206):     return Provider<Example>(
I/flutter (30206):       create: (_) => Example(),
I/flutter (30206):       // Will throw a ProviderNotFoundError, because `context` is associated
I/flutter (30206):       // to the widget that is the parent of `Provider<Example>`
I/flutter (30206):       child: Text(context.watch<Example>()),
I/flutter (30206):     ),
I/flutter (30206):   }
I/flutter (30206):   ```
I/flutter (30206): 
I/flutter (30206):   consider using `builder` like so:
I/flutter (30206): 
I/flutter (30206):   ```
I/flutter (30206):   Widget build(BuildContext context) {
I/flutter (30206):     return Provider<Example>(
I/flutter (30206):       create: (_) => Example(),
I/flutter (30206):       // we use `builder` to obtain a new `BuildContext` that has access to the provider
I/flutter (30206):       builder: (context) {
I/flutter (30206):         // No longer throws
I/flutter (30206):         return Text(context.watch<Example>()),
I/flutter (30206):       }
I/flutter (30206):     ),
I/flutter (30206):   }
I/flutter (30206):   ```
I/flutter (30206): 
I/flutter (30206): If none of these solutions work, consider asking for help on StackOverflow:
I/flutter (30206): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/flutter
I/flutter (30206): 
I/flutter (30206): The relevant error-causing widget was:
I/flutter (30206):   BeaconList file:///F:/apps/rivi_mvp/lib/screens/home/home.dart:43:19
I/flutter (30206):
````

I've tried a lot of different things but I don't think I understand StreamBuilders and Providers and streams enough to find a solution. Any Solutions or insights would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: why you use provider?

Answer (score 0):

So after messing about with this for 2 days I have found a solution that works for me.

By replacing the `StreamBuilder` with a `StreamProvider<List<Beacon>>.value` this allowed me to access the data appropriately from the BeaconList widget tree using

`final beacons = Provider.of<List<Beacon>>(context) ?? [];`.

In terms of the actual stream - I had data in the Firestore that in code was written as

`{Beacons: [{bid: "1234",}, {bid: "2345",}, {bid: "3456",}]}`.

So for the code for the stream, to format this data I used

```
List<Beacon> _beaconListFromSnapshot(QuerySnapshot snapshot) {
    List<Beacon> x = [];
    return snapshot.documents.map((doc) {
      for (Map data in doc.data["Beacons"]) {
        x.add(Beacon(bid: data["bid"],));
      }
      return x;
    }).toList()[0];
  }

  Stream<List<Beacon>> get brews {
    return beaconCollection.snapshots().map(_beaconListFromSnapshot);
  }
```

If anyone can come up with a more efficient or more eloquent solution or pointers towards one then I would be very grateful.